# C# speed up webclient download

Tags: c#, webclient

How to speed up downloading html source code of website by url in a loop?

I'm using this code to download, but it's quite slow. (avg download time ~5s per url)

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        var source_code = client.DownloadString(url[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: With sockets you could do this on parallel.

Comment: This is like asking whether 20mph is a "normal" speed. For a caterpillar? No, it's way too fast. For a plane? No, it's way too slow. For a car? Maybe, depending on traffic...

Comment: I depends on your URLs.

Comment: Is your webpage poorly optimized? What is `url` and more specifically what is `url[i]`. None of this code makes sense in the current context to be honest.

Comment: I don't think your edit really added anything that helps :|

Comment: Have you tried using a HttpClient, or a HttpWebRequest? There are a number of factors that could cause a slow network.

Comment: @ColinM I tried HttpWebRequest and got the same download time.

Comment: See my answer below, fire off all request asynchronously using the same `HttpClient` and perform your job on the response, that way you're not sequentially fetching the HTML per URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously can't speed up each single download but you can download the contents of several urls in parallel. There are a lot of ways to do that, here is one using `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
var urls = new List<string>() { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com" };
var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        results[url] = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    }
});
```

The results are stored in the `ConcurrentDictionary` with the URL as key, so after the loop has completed you can extract the downloaded code. You'll probably need to add some code to introduce error handling and maybe add some reasonable timeouts, but I hope this will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you're scraping the data from 20 different urls, and if none of these calls  depends on the others, why do you do it in a loop?  Why not make 20 different [asynchronous calls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async) using 20 different web clients? Then, when they are all done, you can stitch the results together.

Something like:

```
// Start the HandleFile method.
Task<string> task1 = ScrapeUrl(url1);
Task<string> task2 = ScrapeUrl(url2);
Task<string> task3 = ScrapeUrl(url3);
...


// Control returns here before scraping is done.

Console.WriteLine("Please wait patiently...");

// Wait for the scraping tasks to complete.
// ... Display its results.
string result1 = await task1;
string result2 = await task2;
string result3 = await task3;
...
```

Comment: Or, 20 requests with one `HttpClient`

Comment: I'd suggest `Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, ...)` otherwise all tasks will be executed in order.

Answer (score 0):

To post another option like the answers have so far, here's a version that uses only one instance of a `HttpClient` in an `async` method, you can basically spin off 20 jobs and fetch the HTML content from your URLs in those jobs, once the jobs are started then you can wait for those all to finish.

The reason I have posted this along with the other answers is because you don't need multiple instances of a Client per URL if you use a HTTP Client.

```
private async Task GetAuctionData()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var downloadTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // Perform work here on HttpClient
                });
            tasks.Add(downloadTask);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```